# MySQL: ORDER BY and GROUP BY together

Tags: mysql

I recently upgraded to MySQL 5.7.22 and my query stopped working.  I have two tables "items" and "packages" where I'm trying to output a row for each item including a column for the package with the minimum price per unit, but ignore packages that have a price per unit set to 0.

Here's a minimal sample of tables and data:

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE `packages` (
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price_per_unit` float(16,6) DEFAULT 0
);


INSERT INTO `items` (`id`) VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3);


INSERT INTO `packages` (`item_id`, `price_per_unit`) VALUES
(1, 0.45),
(1, 0),
(1, 0.56),
(1, 0.34);
```

Here's the query:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (
  SELECT
    items.id,
    NULLIF(pkgs.ppu, 0) AS mppu
  FROM
    items
  LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      item_id,
      price_per_unit AS ppu
    FROM
      packages
  ) AS pkgs ON pkgs.item_id = items.id
  ORDER BY
    IFNULL(mppu, 9999)
  ) X
GROUP BY
  X.id
```

I was setting the zero values to null and then bumping their values to be much higher during the ordering.  There must be a better way (especially since this method doesn't work any longer).

The expected output for this data is:

```
id    mppu
1     0.34
2     null
3     null
```

Comment: `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm not sure why you would say that SELECT * with GROUP BY doesn't make sense.  The goal is to show all of the column.  They are used together all of the time.

Comment: . . Absolutely not.  MySQL has finally fixed the problem that allowed it in earlier versions.  Although you can override the setting, MySQL now conforms to the SQL standard and behaves the way other databases do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your query is a bit too complex. What about this?

```
SELECT i.id,IFNULL(Min(p.price_per_unit), 'NONE')
FROM   items i
       LEFT JOIN packages p
              ON ( i.id = p.item_id )
WHERE  p.price_per_unit > 0
        OR p.price_per_unit IS NULL
GROUP  BY i.id
```

See this [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sbTyQbNemcEM5vX3xwuUaJ/0). I used this data:

```
INSERT INTO `items` (`id`) VALUES
(1),(2),(3);


INSERT INTO `packages` (`item_id`, `price_per_unit`) VALUES
(1, 0.45),
(1, 0),
(1, 0.56),
(1, 0.34),
(2, 9.45),
(2, 0),
(2, 0.56),
(2, 0.14);
```

And got this result:

```
id  IFNULL(min(p.price_per_unit),'None')
1   0.340000
2   0.140000
3   None
```

Comment: but, I'm still not sure how you want the table ordered. By ascending id? by price per unit?

Comment: This doesn't satisfy the requirement to show all of the items.  (The sample data only had one item, but add a couple more).

Comment: BTW, some items will not have any packages.  I think that's why the other items are not showing up.  I'll update the question with the additional items.

Comment: @Simpler - what should it show if there are no prices or if the only price available is zero?

Comment: It should show 'null' if there are no packages.  If there are only packages with prices of zero, then an output of zero is reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with [GL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff),

> SELECT * FROM GROUP BY

is not predictable .

i will rewrite the query with :

```
SELECT a.*,b.min_price_per_unit
FROM items a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT item_id
        ,min(CASE 
                WHEN price_per_unit = 0
                    THEN 9999
                ELSE price_per_unit
                END) AS min_price_per_unit
    FROM packages
    GROUP BY item_id
    ) b ON a.id = b.item_id;
```